# How can I install jython on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, jython

I have downloaded "jython-installer-2.7-b1.jar". I want to install it on Windows 7. What are the steps can I follow? Please guide me.

Answer (score 5):

Pre requisite: Installation of Java

Follow the following steps:

1. Run "jython-installer-2.7-b1.jar" as below command:
   java -jar jython-installer-2.7-b1.jar
2. Follow the instruction from Jython Installation pop up
3. After successful installation set PATH as C:\jython2.7b1\bin
4. Open command prompt and execute the command as below:
   jython --version
5. The output as "Jython 2.7b1" would verify the complete installation and setting path

Comment: step 3: there is no bin folder. should be instead c:\jython2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I followed @RiponAlWasim  answer but at the first step the installer stopped saying unable to create directory

To solve this problem **Open command prompt as administrator**